# removing space in mixed content element without using normalize-space

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I get my input like this:

```
<p><span class="someclass"/> Tekst <i>italic</i> etc..</p>

<p> Tekst <i>italic</i> etc..</p>
```

I would like the output to be:

```
<p><span class="someclass"/>Tekst <i>italic</i> etc..</p>

<p>Tekst <i>italic</i> etc..</p>
```

If I use normalize-space(.) in a mixed content model I will also remove the space before and after the <i>-element.

```
<p><span class="someclass"/>Tekst<i>italic</>etc..</p>

<p>Tekst<i>italic</i>etc..</p>
```

Is there a nice way to work around this?

Comment: Can you explain in words which spaces you want to remove? Only the leading space of the first text node child of a `p`? In that case `<xsl:template match="p/text()[1]"><xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s+`, '')"/></xsl:template>` might do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is remove leading white space in the first `text()` child node of a `p` element then using XSLT 3.0 you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="p/text()[1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s+', '')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and using XSLT 2.0 you have to spell out `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` as the identity transformation template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/text()[1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s+', '')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks again for your answer. I was kind of working with p/text()[1] and replacing, but the trouble was the identy transformation template ... like don't having it :)
So output stayed the same :)